# Why is syncretism mostly described through an "interpretatio graeca", rather than any other polytheism?

Tags: ancient-rome, religion, ancient-greece, hinduism

Ancient Greeks such as Herodotus thought other culture's gods (e.g. Egyptian) are actually same deities as theirs, just having different names.

For example, Plutarch said

> Not different gods for different peoples, not non-Greek and Greek,
> not southern and northern gods; but just as sun and moon and earth and
> sea are common to all men, though they are called by different names
> by different peoples, so of the Reason (Logos) that orders all things,
> and of one Providence that also directs powers ordained to serve under
> her for all purposes, have different honours and titles been made
> according to their laws by different nations.

As I quoted above, there are many evidences that shows Greeks thought other gods are same as their gods, and by doing so they syncretized other culture's mythology.

But basically, all ancient polytheism was not exclusive, so I believe not only ancient Greece (and Rome), but also other cultures had a discourse used to interpret or attempt to understand the mythology of other cultures by using their own mythology, so-called "interpretatio OOO".

I know that there is "Interpretatio germanica", but it seems it was not a dominant practice compared to the Greeks'(and Roman's).

[Simek emphasizes the paucity of evidence for a widespread interpretatio germanica, as opposed to the well-attested opposite interpretatio romana, and notes that comparison with Roman gods is insufficient to reconstruct ancient Germanic gods, or equate them definitively with those of later Norse mythology.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpretatio_germanica)

**Q1. Why is this phenomenon prominent (or 'seems too prominent') only in Greece among other polytheistic countries? For example, why we can't find such records (or 'can find only few evidences') in ancient Hinduism? Why there is no word such as "interpretatio China", "interpretatio Egypt"..etc?**

**Q2. Who first used 《term》 'interpretatio Graeca'? I believe that term was coined quite recently, but I'm not sure.**

Comment: This might be a good candidate for a question to be moved to [the Mythology site](https://mythology.stackexchange.com/) if you'd prefer answers from experts in Mythology.

Comment: In cases where said gods are equated to celestial bodies, the equation would seem both obvious and necessary, no?

Comment: @MCW I accidently removed my comment :( Anyway thank you for your advices. I have changed few things about my post.

Comment: Are you confusing familiarity with frequency? The Greco-Roman tradition is the cultural, historical and religious base for most Western European, including English-language, societies. Why wouldn't those habits be seen as "*prominent*", even if not actually so? What is the actual basis for your claim, as opposed to it being simply an attempt to promote or discredit a particular viewpoint?

Comment: @T.E.D. It is not obvious such an equation works for planets - and can get worse even in a single culture: Venus was a goddess of love as well as being the planet, but the same planet was also called Phosphorus/Lucifer in the morning and Hesperus/Vesper in the evening when thought of as two, a pair of male half-brothers

Comment: I don't have the time, but I wonder if this is a first mover phenomenon (the first author, circa 1939 was most familiar with Graeco), or a proximity problem (Graeco Roman equivalence were closer and easier to model); seems like it should be possible to research. Are there any records of non-Graeco-Roman models?  How is the scholarly literature expressed? What do the citations in Wikipedia say about the problem?

Comment: Questions of the form "why is so much/not enough  attention being paid to X" are almost always opinion-based.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens In fact, the claim is also just untrue. Anyone who studies ancient Mesopotamian/Near Eastern religious interactions are very comfortable equating equating Sumerian and Akkadian deities.

Comment: @cmw: What claim are you referring to as "[t]he claim"? I can't determine the antecedent for that referential phrase.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens The topic in the title: "Why is syncretism mostly described through an "interpretatio graeca", rather than any other polytheism?"

Comment: @cmw: Got it; thank you. I agree.

Answer (score -1):

### The Greeks Weren't Wrong

The Greeks saw themselves as surrounded by people who worshiped the same gods under different names because they **were literally surrounded by people who worshiped the same gods under different names!**

### PIE

Greek is a [Proto-Indo-European](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indo-European_languages) (PIE) language, which is to say it can be traced to the people who first [domesticated the horse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domestication_of_the_horse) North of the Black Sea in roughly 3,500 BC.

It turns out that that basically all of Europe (including notably Germany, Italy, and the Balkans) as well as Anatolia (Troy, Hittites, etc) and Persia (Parthia) also spoke PIE languages. It stands to reason that the [PIE religion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_mythology) spread with the language.

### Exceptions

The Semantic speakers of the Levant, as well as the Egyptians and Sumerians all came from different language families and obviously would not have inherited PIE myths, but they may have been influenced by them. The presence of the Flood Myth in early Vedic and Greek sources suggests that it may be PIE in origin, would would imply a PIE influence on both the myths of the Levant (Biblical Flood) and Sumer (Gilgamesh Flood).

It may be that the Levant and Mesopotamian cultures absorbed enough of PIE myths from Anatolia, Persia, and Greece into their own religion that they became recognizable - especially if the Greeks were already accustomed to finding their "own" gods in other cultures.

Comment: I'd be interested in reasons for the downvotes?

Comment: I didn't vote on this at all, but I'm not sure how it really answers the question. Admittedly, though, I don't think the question is well-informed enough.

Comment: @cmw - not that it matters with the question closed, but I was attempting to say that the Corded Ware / Bell Beaker people brought their language and religion with them when they migrated out from the Black Sea area to the rest of Europe. The same way that all Christian religions are similar because they can be traced to the Levant around 2000 BP, all pre-Christian European religions were similar because they can be traced to North of the Black Sea circa 5500 BP. The Greeks saw parallels between Odin All-Father and Zeus Pater because they both descended from the older PIE god Dyeus Phter.

Comment: (continued) thus the Greeks were fundamentally *correct* when they identified Roman, Anatolian, Baltic and Germanic gods as being Greek gods by other names. They are all PIE gods whose names and attributes have drifted apart over centuries. The Egyptians, by contrast, were not surrounded by other civilizations with a common linguistic / religious root. So they *also correctly* didn't see themselves as surrounded by Egyptian gods called by other names.

Comment: The thing is, though, they did draw equivalences between Egyptian gods and Greek gods. Zeus was Ammon, Osiris was Dionysus, Thoth was Mercury, and so forth. The did a similar thing with Phoenician gods. The situation led to Cicero talking about multiple Hercules, one who was born in Thebes, another who was prominent among the Phoenicians (and I believe refers to Melqart).

Comment: @cmw - The direct answer is we probably don't have enough data. But I proposed two potential explanations under "Exceptions": a) Greeks were primed by all the other PIE myths in neighboring cultures and shoe-horned the Egyptians, Phoenicians, etc. into "everyone worships our gods by other names." or b) over time, the PIE myths bled into surrounding cultures enough that the Greeks legitimately could see reflexes of PIE gods. The Divine Twins might be a good example of this: Cain and Able fit very neatly into a PIE myth tradition in spite being a Biblical (Semantic) story.

Comment: I'm not asking the question, someone else did. I'm actually fairly familiar with this area, and did my MA level thesis work on a very closely related topic. The actual short answer is that Greece's neighbors have a long history of making equivalences between gods going all the way back to 2500 BCE or so when Akkadians and Sumerians were close neighbors. Inanna of the Sumerians was equivalent to Ishtar of the Akkadians, etc.

Comment: But it seems that it's more than historical. What motivated the Romans to connect Mercurius and Lug(us) was more about what they were doing, not that they shared a long kinship with Gauls. And the Greeks of all people were more closely interacting with non-IE groups (Hittites and Luwians aside, they traded with Phoenicians and built a settlement in Egypt and served in the army of the Assyrians).

Comment: I don't think it's quite so much "those Egyptian gods are our gods" or "our gods are actually Egyptian" but "here's this deity power: in Greece we call that power Zeus, and in Egypt they call that power Ammon." In the same way they would think that in Greece they call bread μᾶζα but the Romans called it *panis*.

Comment: A good first source if you want to see how the Romans and Germans did it is Rives' [chapter](https://www.academia.edu/5387637/Roman_Translation_Tacitus_and_Ethnographic_Interpretation), which he put up on his Academia.edu page. But there are a ton of resources on "interpretatio graeca/romana" and general Mediterranean syncretic practices.

Comment: (Sorry to keep adding on to this, but interestingly I found one more piece of evidence: the Romans actually [equated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odin#Roman_era_to_Migration_Period) Odin with Mercury, not with Zeus!)

Comment: If the PIE peoples were living on the north shore of the Black Sea 7600 years ago: perhaps the origin of the "*flood story*" was [an actual flood of that region](https://animations.geol.ucsb.edu/2_infopgs/IP2IceAge/fBlackSeaFlood.html).